# Active Directory security - is user on computer?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a task to select specific group of computers. Their unique property is that their security list contains permission for specific user. In AD tool - right click on computer, Security tab, Group or user names as seen on screenshot: 
[image: AD screenshot]

I can get the ComputerPrincipal object of relevant host, UserPrincipal of user, and both underlying DirectoryEntry objects, but I struggle to make a "join" and find if user is on the list.

I use C#, .NET3.5.

Comment: Hello Anton, could you please share, how you fix this issue. or does Gabriel Luci's solution help you to find the user from security group ? thank you

Comment: As far as remember (don't have the access to code) it was getaccesrules() call, and my mistake was just accessing wrong properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to loop through every group, and for each group you could do something like this (assuming you have a `groupDe`, which is a DirectoryEntry for the group):

```
foreach (var identityReference in groupDe.ObjectSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier)) {
    var nt_name = identityReference.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
    //nt_name.Value is now domain\username of the user this permission is for
    //so you can match this against your list of users
}
```

The `false` in the call to `GetAccessRules` makes it not look at inherited permissions (I assumed that's what you want).

I haven't tested this, so it might need some tweaking.

This will probably be a very slow process, depending on how many groups you're looking through. You might be able to make it go faster by omitting the call to `Translate`. `identityReference.Value` would have (I believe) a SID, so you could try to match by SID rather than translating to something else before matching.